# XCODE 13.2: Multiple commands produce Build Error

Tags: xcode, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to build a project using Google FireStore.
I was able to compile fine yesterday. I had the auth working.
I added a couple swift files today and I keep getting this build error.

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/isai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/bwoae-civvqqnndameofcwxddefhbquxiy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/bwoae.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/bwoae.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewExtensions.stringsdata':
1) Target 'bwoae' (project 'bwoae') has compile command for Swift source files
2) Target 'bwoae' (project 'bwoae') has compile command for Swift source files
```

I checked my "Copy Bundle Resources" Section. I do not have a duplicate plist file.
[image]

I even tried deleting everything under "Copy Bundle Resources" .
I still have this error.

Can someone please shed some light here and help me get rid of this error ?

Thank You.

Comment: This is why you're using version control. Just revert to how things were when everything was compiling.

Comment: If you can switch, using SPM rather than CocoaPods for this seems to be much lower friction.

Comment: I am using SPM.

Comment: on what line in your code produces this error?

Comment: it does not show a line number.